# eclipse cannot find stdarg.h

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android ndk, and i'm trying to make a fully native application. I'm using eclipse, and i'm getting this warning:

```
Unresolved inclusion: <stdarg.h>
```

along with unknown type errors for the types i try to use in that header.

I'm wondering if someone here could tell me how to get eclipse to find stdarg.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake when adding the paths and symbols directories

first go to project->properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols

Then add

```
${env_var:ANDROID_NDK}\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.4.3\include
```

for all languages